# Creating a zoom in control on a report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to build a pop up zoom box which will be activated on a report embedded in a form allowing the user to click on the report and view a field on the underlying table which the report is demonstrating. Furthermore, the user will also have the opportunity to edit the fields contents which the zoom box, upon closing will then paste into the field in the underlying table.

A colleague of mine confirmed for me that this is possible and put me on the right track by showing me that it is possible to extract a field by creating a control on a report.   However, i am missing the part to repaste the updates into the underlying field.

Being a report, Sift F2 does not allow the edit..

I would appreciate any advice available. 
Thanks, 
A

Comment: OK...  For me the first step seems to be to get the information in the control of the report (which is named 'Notes') to paste into the zoom in window screen which is a form I called frmZoom02..

Comment: my routine upon opening the pop up window is:    Me.txtZoom = Forms("frmContactsSwitchboard").Report("rptContactPage05")!Notes

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not doing the trick..  I think my reference to the report is not recognised. The Naming convention must be wrong..    Again, the main form is called frmContactsSwitchboard and the report embedded within it is called rptContacPage05

Comment: What does `Me.txtZoom` have for its Control Source property?

Comment: excuse me. "txtZoom" is the name of the control i created on the zoom in window (form) where the user will see the informatoin being extracted from the report

Comment: I understand.  What is it's Control Source property?  Is there something there, or is that property blank?

Comment: the control source property is blank

Comment: Hans, i to fix the pop up window to pop up as a window i need to add the following code in the open form code:  " acNormal, , , , acDialog"  do you have any idea as to how i can insert this into the code you wrote with me??  "DoCmd.OpenForm "frmZoom2", WhereCondition:="[ID] = " & Me.txtPrimaryKey"

Comment: I think you are saying:'frmForm1' contains an embedded subrport 'rptReport1'. When user selects a field (double-click?), form (frmZoom) opens and shows either just that value, or several values from that row? And the user needs to update that value in the underlying field(s) in the proper tables. Since there is no 'binding' between rptReport1 and frmZoom, you would need to pass all info required to update (i.e. key field of the report row, field value the user clicked on), then perform your update via either SQL command or recordset editing. Plus requery the report content?

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua See whether you find it easier by including the option names.  `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmZoom2", View:=acNormal, WhereCondition:="[ID] = " & Me.txtPrimaryKey, WindowMode:=acDialog`  Also check out the `DoCmd.OpenForm` help topic in Access' online help system.  You'll be glad to make friends with that feature.  :-)

Comment: Grande Hans"!! Once again correct.. Thanks alot for all your help

Comment: @ Hans..  My next question, which i may post tonight before I go to bed may be exciting for you as well and perhaps you may want to comment..  Basically, on the same report which we are working with, i need to add also a check box so that the user can select multiple records. I think after what we did today, the concept will be similar but alone i dont know if i will arrive..   If you have any suggestions or shortcuts im all ears.  thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it is kind of interesting, but I have too many other fish to fry.  You're welcome to email me sometime if you wish.  I believe I can offer you guidance to help you scale the Access learning curve faster.

Answer (score 2):

Fantastic effort given by HansUp in live chat directing me to exactly what i needed!

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmZoom2", WhereCondition:="[ID] = " & Me.txtPrimaryKey